# Remove gestures from Android Q

Tags: java, gesture, android-10.0

I have a kids drawing app, but the gestures in Q keep quitting the app. I tried removing the system gesture but it does not seem to work.

In this case, I am trying to exclude the whole screen from system gesture:

```
List<Rect> exclusionRects = new ArrayList();

public void onLayout(boolean changedCanvas, int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        exclusionRects.clear();
        exclusionRects.add(new Rect(left, top, right, bottom));
        setSystemGestureExclusionRects(exclusionRects);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

As stated by Google:

> First, to ensure reliable and consistent operation, there’s a 200dp vertical app exclusion limit for the Back gesture.

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2019/08/final-beta-update-official-android-q.html

This means that the operating system will not allow you to override the back gesture fully.

This makes sense as it is a fairly fundamental part of the operating system and they probably don't want to allow apps that remove the gesture entirely, as it is bad for consistency across the platform

Comment: What does "200dp vertical app exclusion limit" mean? Isn't the back gesture is on the left (horizontal)?

Comment: The back gesture is on both the left and right sides, and these are both vertical edges (vertical = up <-> down, horizontal = left <-> right). This means that of the full height of the screen, only 200dp are allowed to be excluded from gesture navigation. I.e. if your screen is 1000dp high, a minimum of 800dp will be used for the gesture no matter what.

Comment: _"This makes sense"_ - except that now every drawing app is fundamentally broken because you can't draw on the left/right side of the screen without navigating?  wtf??

Comment: The three-button navigation mode still exists, but IMO it's a worthwhile tradeoff. I disagree that having a few pixels on either edge of the screen unusable "fundamentally breaks" drawing apps. And even if it does, I'd rather have this than allow apps that I download from the internet (without vetting source code) to disable navigating away from the app.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

1. Define this code in your Utils class.

   ```
    static List<Rect> exclusionRects = new ArrayList<>();
    public static void updateGestureExclusion(AppCompatActivity activity) {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) return;
      exclusionRects.clear();
      Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, SystemUtil.dpToPx(activity, 16), getScreenHeight(activity));
      exclusionRects.add(rect);

      activity.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setSystemGestureExclusionRects(exclusionRects);
    }

    public static int getScreenHeight(AppCompatActivity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    int height = displayMetrics.heightPixels;
    return height;
    }

    public static int dpToPx(Context context, int i) {
      return (int) (((float) i) * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
    }
   ```
2. Check if your layout is set in that activity where you want to exclude the edge getures and then apply this code.

   ```
    // 'content' is the root view of your layout xml.
    ViewTreeObserver treeObserver = content.getViewTreeObserver();
    treeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            content.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            SystemUtil.updateGestureExclusion(MainHomeActivity.this);
        }
    });
   ```

- We are adding the view width to 16dp to trigger the code when user swipe right from left edge & height to screen height to do it fully left side.

Comment: This code works for the whole left edge, for bottom & right edge, you just need to add Rects in the arraylist like written above.