# How to use Window.setSystemGestureExclusionRects() in a service with overlay windows?

Tags: android, android-service, overlay

I have an overlay service which is activated from the edge of the screen and I want to implement `View.setSystemGestureExclusionRects()` for the edge. [The documentation says](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/gesturenav?hl=en#games) that `Window.setSystemGestureExclusionRects()` can be used for apps with no view hierarchy, but how can I use it in the service if there is no way to get a reference to the `Window` object from the service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding view to the service then you can exclude rectangles using that method. Because you can get window from the view's windowmanager.

you can find [here](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/add-view-outside-activity-through-windowmanager-1a70590bad40) that windowmanager is being used to add view in the service outside of an activity. So you can get `window` from that after adding the view.

If you want to eclude the gestures in your desired area, then you can follow my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65338432/10357086).